# how to find a date from the value of week of the month in laravel..?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I need to find first, second, etc, week in a month.
  In that week, i need to find a Monday/Tuesday or else.
  I'm using laravel framework and php,

Now, i'm going to find Monday of first week of this September month and
  my code is,

```
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+0 week, Monday', strtotime('first day of September 2016')));
```

This is correct way or not..?
  Here, the answer is no date or 5-9-2016 ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler than you think using `strtotime`. I believe the last few are what you're after. You'll have to be careful though, some weeks in partiular months may not have a particular day. For instance the 1st week of November 16 does not have a Monday.

```
<?php

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('first monday September 2016')); 
// 2016-09-05 (first Monday of september '16)

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('Tuesday +1 week December 2016')); 
// 2016-12-06 (first Tuesday of December '16)

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('Friday November 2016')); 
// 2016-11-04 (first Friday of November '16')

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('fourth Monday September 2016')); 
// 2016-09-05 (first Monday of september '16)

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('Tuesday December 2016')); 
// 2016-12-06 (first Tuesday of December '16)

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('third Friday November 2016')); 
// 2016-11-04 (first Friday of November '16')

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('Tuesday +1 week December 2016')); 
// 2016-12-06 (Tuesday of the second week of December '16)

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('Friday +2 week November 2016')); 
// 2016-11-04 (Friday of the third week of November '16')
?>
```

Without the '+n week' in the last 2 examples, it's going to return the first matching day in the first week.  Adding `+1 week` makes it the second week it chooses the day from. Adding `+2 week` makes it the third week it chooses from, etc.

But like I mentioned above, it's not foolproof.  For instance:

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('Friday +4 week November 2016'))
// 2016-12-02 Although there are 5 calendar weeks in November '16, the 5th   
// week does not have a Friday.  So you're getting December's Friday, because 
// you're simply adding weeks to a day.
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. But, i need a clarity of 5-9-2016 => Monday is first week of the month or not. Please help me out of this one.

Comment: After your answer, i try this date("Y-m-d",strtotime('first Monday September 2016')); and get "2016-09-05"
But need clarity on is it first week of September month..? and this Monday is a first week day of the September month..? Please help me on it.

Comment: That was not your question.  Your question was "I need to find first, second, etc, week in a month. In that week, i need to find a Monday/Tuesday or else." Now you're asking a different question.  "Given a date, is it in the first, second, etc. week of the month".

Comment: Sorry, I not said your answer is wrong. Please try to understand me. My main doubt on this only if you take the calendar from mac system, the September month have 1 to 3 in a 1st row, 4 to 10 in 2nd row and so on. I get confusion on here is this month have Monday on the first week or second week.  but, our code will 5-9-2016 (Monday) for the first week of the September. It is correct or not..? this is my major doubt. Please help me.

Comment: But, i get some point from your answer. Thank you for your support on this topic. If you get any idea on above comment please add to it.

Comment: I think it might help you to repose your question with more specific details. So much depends on things like what day your week starts... Saturday? Sunday? Monday? But I don't think you can accomplish what you're asking with just strtotime. Also look into DateInterval objects. You can use those to help you find differences between dates for your comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

I would higly recommend you to read about [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs), it comes by default with Laravel and is what is used internaly to deal with dates. Also is really handy and easy to use.